# how to calculate a parallel product in ispc

Tags: avx, avx2, ispc

the following code does not work because ISPC refuses to compile a function that returns a varying variable from an exported function. Is there any way to do this?
Manually in AVX I would calculate products in parallel, then compute the products of all the pieces. The change in the order of the multiplies will change the answer, which perhaps is why ISPC is so nervous about this.

```
export double prod(uniform double a, uniform double b, uniform int n) {
  uniform double dx = (b-a)/n;

  double prod = 1;
  double x = a;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, x += dx) {
    prod *= x;
  }
  return prod;
}
```

Comment: I've never used ISPC, but you should quote it's exact error message if there is one.

Comment: I'm not sure the order actually matters in this particular case. Multiply the sum of `i` by `dx`, as in `prod = n * (n-1) / 2 * dx`, eliminating the loop. If this is just an example, try to remove the order dependency as in `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { prod *= i * dx; }`. Slower, but that should be made up for by being parallelize-able.

Comment: I don't know ISPC either. Does `double x;` initialize `x` in some way? Otherwise your code probably results in undefined behavior. Did you mean to initialize `x=a` maybe?